# How to assign a Mouseaction to Mousewheel Up/Down / Zoom Text

Tags: intellij-idea

The option to zoom text with ctrl + mousewheel is gone. Now in the editor i can add a keymap for increase font size.

However, i cannot add ctrl+mousewheel/up/down.

I can only click for mouse actions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It isn't gone. It was introduced a while ago and it works perfectly under IntelliJ 14.0.3.

> **To enable changing font size in the editor**
>
> Open the IDE Settings dialog.On the Editor page, make sure that the setting Change font size (Zoom) with Ctrl+MouseWheel is enabled.

`Settings > Editor > General > Check "Change font size (zoom) with Ctrl + Mouse Wheel"`

[Source](https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/help/zooming-in-the-editor.html)

Comment: Thanks, the online help wasnt specific about the category general